# htaccess not redirecting properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So with a new apache version on my local development server this works flawlessly. I've moved it over to a live server, specs below:

- CentOS 6.2 LAMP (x64)
- PHP Version 5.4.30
- Apache/2.2.15

**The Problem**

Most of the PHP functions from what I can tell break because of this, - pages aren't displayed properly and content doesn't load.

However, the direct rules is supposed to redirect to a variant of `index.php?p=xxx` but instead it remains as `mydomain.com/index.html`

However the content does actually display (partially).

**Steps taken thus far**

Edited httpd.conf - specfically `<Directory "/var/www/html">` and changed `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

Before I did this it wouldn't display any content on the page, after doing this it's displaying content but the URL's aren't being redirected properly.

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule main.html$ index.php 
RewriteRule login.html$ index.php?p=login 
RewriteRule logout.html$ index.php?logout=true 

RewriteRule add-user.html$ index.php?p=add_user 
RewriteRule users-list.html$ index.php?p=users_list 
RewriteRule users-list-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?p=users_list&page=$1 
RewriteRule users-list-delete-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?p=users_list&delete=$1 
RewriteRule edit-user-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?p=profile&id=$1 
RewriteRule profile.html$ index.php?p=profile 
RewriteRule sites-list.html$ index.php?p=sites_list 
RewriteRule sites-list-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?p=sites_list&page=$1 
RewriteRule sites-list-delete-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?p=sites_list&delete=$1 
RewriteRule sites.html$ index.php?p=sites 
RewriteRule edit-site-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?p=sites&id=$1 
RewriteRule share-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?p=share&id=$1 
RewriteRule share-([0-9]+)-delete-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?p=share&id=$1&del_id=$2 
RewriteRule statistics.html$ index.php?p=home 
RewriteRule configuration.html$ index.php?p=config 
RewriteRule (.*)-site-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?p=site_inner&id=$2
```

**EDIT**

I added `[R=301,L]` to the end of each line and now it redirects to

```
mydomain.com/var/www/html/index.php?logout=true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a rule to stop there, add a [L] to the end to stop checking rules. Otherwise, rewrites keep going until the end of the .htacecss

Comment: I added [L] to the end of every line, - starts of a huge redirect loop. - I then added it to the end of the last line, no change.